# problem with testing in pytest in a In-memory database with peewee

Tags: python, database, pytest, fastapi, peewee

I have a problem creating tables in my in-memory database using peewee in the moment i test a registration user endpoint from fastapi.
My User table:

db.py ->

```
from peewee import Model, CharField, SqliteDatabase, BooleanField, AutoField
import sys

db = SqliteDatabase("database.db")

class BaseTable(Model):
    class Meta:
           database = db

class User(BaseTable):  
    id = AutoField()
    name = CharField(null=False)
    lastname = CharField(null=False)
    email  = CharField(null=False, unique=True)
    password = CharField(null=False)
    is_logged_in = BooleanField(default=False)

if not "pytest" in sys.modules:
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([User])
    db.close()
```

my conftest.py:

```
from main import app
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from peewee import SqliteDatabase
from src.db import User

MODELS = [User]

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return TestClient(app)

@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def db_test():
    test_database = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')
    User._meta.database = test_database
    test_database.connect()
    test_database.create_tables(MODELS)
    yield
    test_database.drop_tables([User])
    test_database.close()
```

and my test in question in my test_registration.py:

```
def test_register_user(client):
    response = client.post('/register_user', data={"name":"GoodName", "lastname":"GoodLastname","email":"goodemail@mail.com","password":"GooDpaSsword1"})
    assert response.json() == {"detail":"User Created"}
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

My error runing the test with pytest is: peewee.OperationalError: no such table: user

in teory, it creates the table user, i did a print(test_database.table_exists(MODELS)) and it gave me "true", i tried instead of ':memory:' -> 'file:foobar_database?mode=memory&cache=shared' and works fine but creates a file named "file" in my proyect, and i just want a memory database, what i am doing wrong?